# file type needed to add layer containing contour lines

Tags: qgis, contour, topography

What file format is usable/recognized by qgis to add contour lines to a map?

I'm working with Linux Mint 15, and qgis 1.7.5

Comment: What do you mean by "manually create"? Do you want to draw/digitize them by hand? Do you want to write code that creates it? Please clarify.

Comment: Primarily, all I'm asking is what file format is it that qgis requires to display contour lines over an area.

Comment: As @ew_gis answered, any of the supported vector file formats will do. They all can contain line data. To answer which one would be best for your use case, we need to know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [supported data formats](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html).  My recommendation would be an ESRI Shapefile.